# Issue with Facebook Omniauth, devise with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth-facebook

I have scoured these pages for weeks looking for an answer.  I am a newbie to Ruby, i followed a tutorial and was able to successfully complete it with little fuss. My issue is when i decided to add more functionality to my app by authenticating users with Facebook using the Omniauth gem in addition to the devise gem that is working perfectly.

I almost know the solution will be simple to the trained eye but i am at a loss since i have tried numerous suggestions on this site and others with varying degrees of success.

My current problem is whenever a user tries to sign in using Facebook, user gets authenticated but is redirected to the signup page. I fiddled around sometime last week and was able to successfully login but just once and kept getting redirected to signup page subsequently.

My required scenario is thus:

If a user clicks on the sign in with Facebook link, they should get redirected to Facebook for authentication, then sent back to my Ruby application and the values for email, first_name, last_name should get added to the User table for that user.

For a returning User,
All database values should be checked and user is logged in automatically without much fuss.

I would also like an email unique constraint to ensure we do not have multiple people with the same email.

I would really appreciate some sort of direction as to where i am getting it wrong.. Like i mentioned above, i am a total greenhorn in this space as i work mainly with IT infrastructure.

Please see my code below:

callbacks_controller.rb

```
 class CallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
   def facebook
   # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. 
   app/models/user.rb)
@user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

if @user.persisted?
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if 
@user is not activated
  set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if 
is_navigational_format?
else
  session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
end

def failure
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

def failure
    redirect_to root_path
    end
   end

user.rb

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable
has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy

#validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
devise :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]


 def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(email: auth.info.email).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
  user.email = auth.info.email
  user.password = Devise.friendly_token[6,20]
  user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
  user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
  user.save
  end


  end

  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
   super.tap do |user|
  if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]
    ["extra"]["raw_info"]
    user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
    user.first_name = data["first_name"] if user.first_name.blank?
    user.last_name = data["last_name"] if user.last_name.blank?
    end
   end
  end
```

routes.rb

```
   Rails.application.routes.draw do

   devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks"}
   resources :hospitals do
   collection do
   get 'search'
   end
   resources :reviews, except: [:show, :index]
    end



    get 'pages/Hospitals'

    get 'pages/Labs'

    get 'pages/Doctors'

    get 'pages/about'

    get 'pages/contact'

    root'hospitals#index'



   # For details on the DSL available within this file, see 
    http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
    end
```

Console Response

```
 Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for ::1 at 2017-06-13 14:02:29 +0100
 I, [2017-06-13T14:02:29.142018 #8385]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request 
 phase initiated.
 Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for ::1 at 2017-06-13 14:02:29 +0100
 I, [2017-06-13T14:02:29.488425 #8385]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request 
 phase initiated.
 Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback
 code=AQAJ33qxsDJhSh2fKc8YH9YANZwK2BagO3fotR22iw3
 cOeTN5G2HSvXbOioiwaQmwrZB3EEZKZBWlBAK4c
 RVyddoG8oaeLQfEXjA0FPOvZtpw0XiuBGwOJIh7YaDSjt7O33Dn2mB7Vlu2YUaT-
 DxlY3ioOVhNx8ymCE6TMGJx0slL-NvMB8b52IHSheMvPYTcMAoj2WXPgrLK8aH0eox_
 7VbD8zaV0QFeJxqask3gaU4GTkGI50liO2SdF
 T9fyFVWTgfORNP0yhwoH3HNlMGIznqSqbRGB43d
 2qULNHglH6exDMCzgpyhD3Bmi2lxzcLc10"
  for ::1 at 2017-06-13 14:02:29 +0100
 I, [2017-06-13T14:02:29.731093 #8385]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback 
 phase initiated.
 Processing by CallbacksController#facebook as HTML
 Parameters: 
 {"code"=>"AQAJ33qxsDJhSh2fKc8YH9YANZwK2BagO3
 fotR22iw3cOeTN5G2HSvXbOioiwaQmwrZB3EEZK
 ZBWlBAK4cRVyddoG8oaeLQfEXjA0FPOvZtpw0XiuBGwOJIh7YaDSjt7O33Dn2mB7Vlu2YUaT-
 DxlY3ioOVhNx8ymCE6TMGJx0slL-
 NvMB8b52IHSheMvPYTcMAoj2WXPgrLK8aH0eox_
 7VbD8zaV0QFeJxqask3gaU4GTkGI50liO2SdFT9fy
 FVWTgfORNP0yhwoH3HNlMGIznqSqbRGB43d2qULNHglH6exDMCzgpyhD3Bmi2lxzcLc10"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* 
  FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL 
  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up
  Completed 302 Found in 265ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

New Console response

```
  User Load (1.0ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = ? 
  AND 
  "users"."uid" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ? [["provider", 
  "facebook"], ["uid", "104903843446146"], ["LIMIT", 1]] (0.1ms) begin 
  transaction (0.1ms) rollback transaction Redirected to 
  localhost:3000/users/sign_up
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
      if @user.persisted?
        sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
        set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
      else
        session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end
    end
  end
```

## model

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      end
    end
```

Comment: I just tried the code above and got the same response.

Comment: are you not logged in after  login with facebook?

Comment: No i am not. It simply redirects to the sign up page.

Comment: Is the fb data save in db?

Comment: It was saved in the DB the very first time it worked (weeks ago)... I tried to reproduce that so i reset the database but i have been unable to save in the db from then on.. so the answer is no

Comment: you mean first time user login properly??

Comment: Should i replace the entire user.rb code with this or simply add to what I currently have?

Comment: New error             user Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = ? AND "users"."uid" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["provider", "facebook"], ["uid", "104903843446146"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up